# Error 404 when post data with AJAX in ASP .NET MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

Good evening, I am adding two entities at the same time with AJAX, I still do not know how to use it very well but what I want is to register a product with its characteristics. My Aplicaction is make in ASP .NET MVC 5

When I click on my submit button I get an error in a google chrome alert. This says: Error 404

My controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        public JsonResult ProductosNuevoGuardar(PRODUCTO p,CARACTERISTICAS_PRODUCTO[] cp)
        {
            p.SUSUREG = "jgarcia";
            p.NESTADO = 1;

            if (ProductoCore.Agregar(p) == true)
            {
                foreach (var item in cp)
                {
                    item.NIDPROD = p.NIDPROD;

                    item.NESTADO = 1;
                    item.SUSUREG = "jgarcia";

                    if (CaracteristicaCore.Agregar(item) == true)
                    {
                        return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }

            return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

---

My Button and my script

```
<input class="btn btn-success btn-block" id="btnGuardarProducto" type="submit" value="Guardar">
```

---

```
var tableArray = new Array();

    $("#regCaracter").click(function () {

        var c = $("#caracter").val();
        var v = $("#valorCaracter").val();

        if ($.trim(c) != '' && $.trim(v) != '') {

            if (numRow == 0) {
                cabecera();
            };

            $('table[id=tbCataracteristica] tbody').append(createRow({ caracter: c, valorCaracter: v }));

            clean();



            item = {};
            item["SDESCARAC"] = c;
            item["SVALOR"] = v;

            tableArray.push(item);


        };
    });


$("#btnGuardarProducto").on('click', function () {
        var url = '@Url.Action("ProductosNuevoGuardar", "Mantenimiento")';


        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "POST",

            data: {

                cp: tableArray
            },
            datatype: 'json',
            ContentType: 'application/json;utf-8',


            success: function (result) {
                window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Productos", "Mantenimiento")';
            },


        }).done(function (resp) {
            alert('Success ' + resp);
        }).error(function (err) {
            alert("Error " + err.status);
        });

    });
```

The error that show me is:

```
jquery.js:9664 POST http://localhost:5256/Mantenimiento/@Url.Action(%22ProductosNuevoGuardar%22,%20%22Mantenimiento%22) 404 (Not Found)
send    @   jquery.js:9664
ajax    @   jquery.js:9215
(anonymous) @   crudProducto.js:89
dispatch    @   jquery.js:4670
elemData.handle @   jquery.js:4338
```

Comment: 404 means that the link you are trying to reach is not accessible. Simply paste the link in Chrome extension postman and issue a post request.

Comment: You are using Razor in javascript to create your URL... is the script in the view or in a separate js file?

Comment: Show the full details of the error. And you need to stringify your data using `data: JSON.stringify({ cp: tableArray })` (and the whole purpose of ajax is to stay on the same page - to use ajax and then redirect using `location.href` is pointless so just make a normal submit and redirect in the POST method)

Comment: I saw that this error came out : 
jquery.js:9664 POST http://localhost:5256/Mantenimiento/@Url.Action(%22ProductosNuevoGuardar%22,%20%22Mantenimiento%22) 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Yes,i use Razor to call my action